Rewrite and send Android Intent
I have a legacy application that consumes an Intent from a industrial device With barcode scanning capabilities.
New tags are being deployed in the warehouse but it takes more time than anticipated and we have to live with old app handling both new tags and old tags.
As a temporary solution (not being able to modify old app), I was thinking of having an Android service in-between that would:

consume Intent fired by the device when scanning new tag
translate this new tag data into the old format (I know how to do this)
broadcast Intent with the old format data for the old app to consume

Are there shortcomings with this approach?
Is it going to drain the battery?

This solution is perfect for your scenario. Is the Intent a Service Intent or a Broadcast Intent?

Broadcast Intent

Is the broadcast Intent explicit or implicit? Does the Intent contain a package name/class name? Can you post the code that sends the new Intent? What is in the Intent?
